# Which version of wxWidgets used in ROS?

Tags: ros, wxwidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that when I install Code::Blocks to try to write wxWidgets, it shows a window to let me choose version of wxWidgets.

```
  1. 2.6.x
  
  2. 2.8.x

  3. 2.9.x (SVN Version)
```

1. Which version used by ROS?
2. What's difference between them? Is higher version compatible with lower version?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12703/which-version-of-wxwidgets-used-in-ros?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses the version of wx bundled with your system.  It appears to be 2.8 in most distributions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1